# Add an joint object to a wireframe modifier

Tags: animation, wireframe

I am trying to add a joint on the vertices of a wireframe modifier (where the lines of the wireframe modifier connect).

This is what I have:

[image]

This is close enough to what I would like:

[image]

(Ideally a joint would appear at **EACH** connection, unlike on the example above where there are several joint objects on some vertices and some don't have a joint object.)

I tried Dupliverts but it didn't work, and I tried a particle hair system but the results I got were very messy.

I can't apply the Wireframe modifier because it's animated with a displace.

Comment: Use a second icosphere and duplivert on it.

Comment: Could you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility, to avoid the duplicate object to be influenced by the wireframe modifier is simply to use another object of the same shape and set the dupli on it.

This second object could be hidden at rendering or simply composed of vertices and edges but no faces:

[image]